# how to process a order items array in wordpress/woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to handle some woocommerce order data into a separate database. Everything works except the list of items.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'handle_order_completed' );
function handle_order_completed( $order_id ){  
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $name = $order->billing_first_name . " " . $order->billing_last_name;
  $billingEmail = $order->billing_email;
  $billingPhone = $order->billing_phone;
  $orderlink = $order->get_view_order_url();
  $products = $order->get_items();
  $orderMeta = get_post_meta($order_id, 'pass_type');

  foreach($products as $prod){
     $sql_insert = <<<SQL
        INSERT INTO cards (cardnumber, name, phone, type, sku)
        VALUES ("$cardnumber", "$name", "$billingPhone", "$type", "$prod['product_sku']")
SQL;
    $prod['product_id'];
  }
```

I need to know what the array keys for the `$order->get_items()` but I can not find a list anywhere. I need the product SKU, product line total, and a custom field I added to the products. I need to use the custom field to decide how to add the other data to the DB.

Comment: Please add more info what you trying to gain/do in this code. Its not clear.

Comment: Where is this information coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get the SKU like this:

```
$product->get_sku() ;
```

In your case:

```
$prod->get_sku() ;
```

I recommend instead of collecting the data manually like you are now, use woocommerce rest-api.

You could or send the id to remote server and then call the order data with order id and save it. Or use the rest api in the same server just to get all order data.

Its quicker and more flexible if you want to get more order info in the future.
https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#orders

Comment: I did consider using the API however it would require more complicated checking code in my other program. (Card balance program for museum passes). I just need the voucher numbers generated from the woocommerce PDF Vouchers plugin and a few details about the order. And it works more stream lined if I have them in the Card Program as cards. I am trying to make this as easy as possible for many volunteers.

Comment: I see. Have you tried to do var_dump on $order->get_items()? Somthing like var_damp($order->get_items()); die();

Comment: No, however the API gave some insight into the the output. Where I did prod['product_sku'] just prod['sku'] was the correct key. $order->get_items() gives an array of the line items. Just like the API. So that hepled however the Woocommerce PDF vouchers which I thought would be meta included with the get_items array its not included in the order at all. Its in its own table I think. So now I need to find the function that gets the info from that table.